# one liner with raise

Tags: python, list-comprehension, raise

How can I put this on one line if it is even possible?

`a = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else raise DnDException("%s is not a number." % i) for i in list_of_strings]`

I want it to do the folowing:

```
a = []
for i in list_of_strings:
    if i.isdigit():
        a.append(int(i))
    else:
        raise DnDException("%s is not a number." % i)
```

Comment: What is the content of `list_of_strings` ? What `DnDException` looks like ?

Comment: list_of_strings is list containing strings. `["1", "2"]`, if the user was naughty then `["I", "will", "break", "this!", "7", "Haha!"]`. `class DnDException(Exception): pass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is *technically* possible as @wim demonstrated, it is more readable to write something like the following, which also works with negative and decimal numbers.

```
try:
    a = list(map(int, list_of_strings))
except ValueError as e:
    raise DnDException(str(e))
```

Update: It looks like you can also do this:

```
class DnDException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(DnDException, self).__init__(*args)
        raise self

list_of_strings = ["I", "will", "break", "this!", "7", "Haha!"]
a = [int(i) if str.isdigit(i) else DnDException("%s is not a number." % i) for i in list_of_strings]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I avoid using `try`

Comment: [The force is strong with this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcUAH.jpg)

Comment: @Selcuk Cool, making `class RaiseDnDException` that raises `DnDException` on construct worked too, but this too doesn't break other raise and has less classes involved.
Does it then call itself during constructing itself and therefor start its own construction twice?

Comment: This is so wrong, I am definitely sticking to this :D

Comment: No, when `__init__` is called the object has already been constructed by the `__new__` method. The only downside I can think of is that you will see an extra line in the tracebacks.

Comment: DnDException is handeled internaly. It is a warning for the user
`except DnDException as exception:
   self.cPrint("?!: %s\n" % exception)`
and I see only one line there
`?!: -1 is not a non-negative integer.` (I fixed the not a number.)

Answer (score 4):

It is technically *possible* to one-liner that:

```
[int(i) if i.isdigit() else (_ for _ in ()).throw(DnDException("%s is not a number." % i)) for i in list_of_strings]
```

Don't tell anyone you heard it from me, though.

Do it like this instead, much more readable:

```
def func(i):
    if i.isdigit():
        return int(i)
    raise DnDException("%s is not a number." % i) 

a = [func(i) for i in list_of_strings]
```

*Note:* Be careful with negative numbers, the string `"-2"` will return `False` for `str.isdigit`.

Comment: Thanks for the Note, however, I am expecting only non-negative integers...

Comment: Is there a simpler construct than `(_ for _ in ())` that can throw things? like `int` or something? or the `Exception` itself?

Comment: Yeah, put it in a function and call the function.

Comment: ...add a constructor to `DnDException` that raises itself.

Comment: @Selcuk I tried `class DnDException(Exception):
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  raise DnDException()`
but I got `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: @Brambor You should raise `self` as it is already constructed. See my updated answer.

Comment: To the _Note_ I am now changing `"%s is not a number."` to `"%s is not a non-negative integer."`. Thanks again.